# Is it idiomatic to use guards when you only have one definition of a function in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Is it idiomatic to use guards when you only have one definition of a function?

eg.

```elixir
defmodule Math do
  def add(a, b) when is_integer(a) and is_integer(b) do
    a + b
  end
end
```

or

```elixir
defmodule Math do
  def add(a, b) do
    a + b
  end
end
```

Which is preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main benefits of guards and pattern-matching in general is to fail early (part of the famous "let it crash" philosophy of erlang/elixir) and to completely prevent the underneath logic to being called at all if inputs do not match your assumptions.

While your `add` example doesn't really need it in the first place, a less trivial function doing actual business logic (say a public function from a phoenix context) could benefit from guards / more restrictive patterns.
If it were to be called with invalid data, it might be:

- harder to debug when it fails deeper in a nested call
- unpredictable and potentially dangerous when it doesn't fail

Of course, guards can only check superficially and detect some obvious errors, they do not replace validating untrusted user input (e.g. with ecto).

This [section about guards and invalid data](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/library-guidelines.html#avoid-working-with-invalid-data) describes it nicely. It is
from a guide to write libraries on Hex, but it specifically states that this philosophy also applies to regular Elixir code.

Comment: Thank you. That link to the library guides was helpful too. Basically pattern match and use guards early to prevent deeply nested errors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is idiomatic to use guard clauses even when you only have a single function clause. Why?  Because **using guards helps to better communicate your intent.**

Coding is easy; communication is hard.

Although adding `@spec`'s and `@doc`'s helps too, the guard unequivocally states what your function accepts, and as others have pointed out, the `FunctionClauseError`  error messages are really in your face -- I think they are easier to debug than whatever weird unpredictable behavior might crop up when you pass your function an unexpected value.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon how specific you want the parameters to be. I have seen `guard` clause being used in function with only one definition in open sourced project like `Oban`. For eg

```
  @doc false
  @spec validate!(Keyword.t()) :: :ok
  def validate!(opts) when is_list(opts) do
    Enum.each(opts, &validate_opt!/1)
  end
```

Comment: If you have multiple `validate!` function definitions I understand the benefit of the guard to distinguish between the function, but if you only have one definition is `is_list` adding anything? All I know is that it will change the error message if called with the wrong types.

Comment: Well, having a guard clause will let the user know that the function is specifically asking for the parameter to be a list and nothing else. I believe that it boils down to how speicifc you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

A guard like this on a single-clause function is basically an assertion on the type of the argument. In your case, calling the function like this:

```elixir
Math.add(7.2, 3.2)
```

results in:

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Math.add/2

    The following arguments were given to Math.add/2:

        # 1
        7.2

        # 2
        3.2
```

so it basically defines an integer-only version of `+`.

The mechanism might be useful if you think the function might be called with improper arguments resulting in obscure or difficult to detect errors. Adding a guard clause like this can make debugging easier by indicating which exact call is the problem and potentially catch the error early.

Comment: So it is mainly changing the error message if called with the wrong types?

Comment: In some cases you might not get an error message at all or the error will happen in another place entirely if you don't add the guard. For example the function might just be constructing a datastructure, like `def build(x, y), do: {x, y}`.